# How to add columns for months in a dataframe at specific locations

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, transpose, tidyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
CONTRACT_ID START_DATE SERVICE  VALUE   year    month
1           01-01-2018    A      10     2018      1
2           01-01-2018    B      20     2018      1
3           01-01-2018    C      30     2018      1
4           01-03-2018    B      40     2018      3
5           01-03-2018    C      50     2018      3
6           01-03-2018    A      60     2018      3
```

And I have converted it to a form like this:

```
CONTRACT_ID year SERVICE 1  3
1           2018    A    10 NA
2           2018    B    20 NA
3           2018    C    30 NA
4           2018    B    NA 40
5           2018    C    NA 50
6           2018    A    NA 60
```

Using reshape function like this:

```
reshape(df, idvar = c("year","CONTRACT_ID","SERVICE"), timevar = "month", direction = "wide")
```

The problem is that in my current dataframe I don't have data for some of the months like we see here for 2(feb). But i would like to add columns for all the missing months like:

```
CONTRACT_ID year SERVICE 1  2  3
1           2018    A    10 NA NA
2           2018    B    20 NA NA
3           2018    C    30 NA NA
4           2018    B    NA NA 40
5           2018    C    NA NA 50
6           2018    A    NA NA 60
```

How do I achieve that. I know that I can add columns in between and in the end, but it doesn't seems efficient. I am creating a script and I want it to be efficient and less time consuming.

EDIT:
As per the suggestion in the comment below, I used `spread` function for widening the data. 
But if I keep `drop = False` the code gives all the combination as output which significantly increases the table size. If I make it TRUE, it doesn't create the combinations but it also removes the Month columns for which I don't have the data, in the current data. I want to keep the columns but not the combinations of CONTRACT_ID, DATE, SERVICE which don't exist. Initially I was removing those rows in subsequent steps but now the size of the table has increased substantially large and I need to handle it while doing the spread of data. 
Any suggestions.

Comment: Do I need to add a new question as I have been trying to find a work around this and failed..and now am running out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
library(tidyr)
long_data <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='
CONTRACT_ID START_DATE SERVICE  VALUE   year    month
1           01-01-2018    A      10     2018      1
                           2           01-01-2018    B      20     2018      1
                           3           01-01-2018    C      30     2018      1
                           4           01-03-2018    B      40     2018      3
                           5           01-03-2018    C      50     2018      3
                           6           01-03-2018    A      60     2018      3
                           ')
long_data
long_data$month <- factor(long_data$month, levels = 1:12, ordered = TRUE)
spread(long_data, key = month, value = VALUE, fill = NA, drop = FALSE)
```

Comment: I have another question: if I keep `drop = False` the code gives all the combination as output which significantly increases the table size. If I make it TRUE, it doesn't create the combinations but it also removes the Month columns for which I don't have the data. I want to keep the columns but not the combinations of CONTRACT_ID, DATE, SERVICE which don't exist. Initially I was removing those rows in subsequent steps but now the size of the table has increased substantially large and I need to handle it while doing the spread of data. Any suggestions.